# C# Designer file: Error rendering control. Designer file out of sync

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have been looking at this for days. I have tried every option in the book and on the web, but have no luck.

There were no changes to the code where I am getting the error, but the designer file is out of sync. To me it seems like the `NoteEditor.ascx.cs` file can't read its control file `NoteDetail.ascx.cs`.

I am not sure why, I have tried deleting the designer file and recreating it. I tried closing all the project tabs and Visual Studio and reopened it, recreated the Designer files with no luck.

The error is that some controls don't have definitions even though they are all defined.

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error you receive? Also it's more likely we can help you if you provide some code.

Comment: hello;Error 5 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'ChangeMode' and no extension method 'ChangeMode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\QRDEV_tO bE uSED\WebSite\DesktopModules\CheckoutSheets\Views\NoteEditor.ascx.cs 70 36 CheckoutSheets

Comment: Please edit your question and don't post this as an (unformatted) comment.

Comment: Every single Method is defined. but when clicking to navigate to definition it say can not navigate to Method definition. for example:

Comment: here is an Error For ReturnUrl in the Note Editor it is used as the foloowing code` NoteDetail.ReturnUrl = Globals.NavigateURL("", Literals.urlInstalledItemId + "=" + installedItemIdAsString);` and The method is defined in NoteDetal.ascs.cs` public string ReturnUrl
        {
            get { return (string)ViewState[vsReturnUrl]; }
            set
            {
                ViewState[vsReturnUrl] = value;
            }
        }
        `I built the project t and it was successful but, rebuilt it again and the error for all the methods within these 2 files were detected

Comment: Please don't paste everything in comments. If you have additional details to provide, update your question and format it appropriately.

Comment: One thought, since you haven't provided any code it's just a guess. Did you accidentally remove the `partial` keyword from your class declaration in the NoteEditor.ascx.cs? That would cause what you're seeing.

Comment: No  I did not remove it. it is is  `public partial NoteEditor.ascx.cs`  to me comapring my project to an original copy of the code the designer is definetely different, the original copy  is building to`protected global::project.Modules.MyProject.Controls.NoteDetail NoteDetail` but in my project it is `protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl NoteDetail;` i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is `ChangeMode` a control within the user control? Is it nested within another control? 
When you look at designer.cs, does the control appear there?
If not then perhaps the designer isn't detecting your control. Try moving it to another location on the user control. Edit the ID, which may force the designer to recognize it. Once that happens you can move the control back to where it was.

Comment: `ChangeMode` is a control within the user control,I believe i is nested within NoteEditor.ascx and NoteDetail.ascx. it does't appear in the designer file. You are correct the designer file IS NOT detecting any controls.I am Not sure what you refer to when you say Edit ID, what are you referring to by ID? I tried moving it and changing the location but with no Luck. Any Ideas to why this might be going on. Thanks